# Dynamically passing JSON/XML to REST web services

Tags: java, json, xml, web-services, rest

I have created a REST web services. Now the application which calls my web services says that will send a Header as RESPONSETYPE with value as JSON or XML. Based on this, I need to produce the response in json/xml. I understand that the **Accept** header can be used by sending the value as **application/xml** or **application/json**. But how can I achieve the dynamic response based on the custom header RESPONSETYPE?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is your REST service built? If you're using something like Jersey this can be done automatically by the framework itself

Comment: It sounds bad. You shouldn't create custom HTTP header when there is an existent and documented one which provides the same functionality. `Accept` request header describes **"Content-Types that are acceptable for the response."** Moreover, most of frameworks can automatically choose the response format according to **`Content-Type`** and **`Accept`** headers.

Comment: is there any way to use custom header to set the format????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by setting the `MediaType` explicitly in your `Response` object.

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Response getSomething(@HeaderParam("your-customer-header") String customHeaderType) {
    return Response.ok(thingYouWantToReturn, mediaTypeFrom(customHeaderType)).build();
}
```

`mediaTypeFrom` is a method you'll need to determine what the actual `MediaType` to return is